# What search options are available with StarTeam?

Tags: starteam

Is it possible with the StarTeam Client to find files in the current server/project/view? What about text in files? File properties (locked by, checked in on *date*, ..., etc)?

I'm just starting to use this software and so far I can't find that feature in the menus or the user's guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the File menu, you can select "Find" to search by file name. (If you want to search all the files in the view I think you need to select "Files In View" and press the "All Descendants" before you go into the File menu.)

You can also setup filters and queries. Basically, a filter determines what columns you see and the query determines what rows you see. To combine them, you can setup a filter and then attach a query to it.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, we check out the complete project from the StarTeam-Server to our harddisk, and then we make a simple search in Windows. That way, you can search on filenames, but also on a textstring in the filecontent. It doesn't seems me to be userfriendly, but you have to make the best out of it... If somebody knows a better solution, don't hesitate to let me know. ( p_dekeyzer@hotmail.com in Flanders, one of the United States of Belgium ).

Comment: Same here, please email me if you find something in this regards: asem.radhwi@gmail.com